# I Allowed CORS, But Still Stuck Login Redirect, API Server Can't save token

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

Thank you for Click it.

#### Summerize

1. [Backend API] -> AWS API gateway Server by serverless framework(serverless-http)
2. [Frontend] -> React.js AWS S3, Cloudfront
3. I typed CORS , Credential both them
4. but still can't login redirect.

### HOW I Developed

- 1. Developed API Backend.

  - Node.js, Koa Framework, MongoDB
  - CRUD + JWT AUTH
  - serverless-http wrapped

#### serverless-http code

```
const handler = serverless(app);

module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  // you can do other things here
  const result = await handler(event, context);
  // and here
  return result;
}
```

and then I Deployed by serverless framework...

#### serverless.yml code

```
plugins:
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-offline

custom:
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
    includeModules: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221

  stage: app
  region: ap-northeast-2

functions:
  api:
    handler: src/server.handler
    events:
      - http: 
          path : /
          method : ANY
      - http: 
          path : /{proxy+}
          method : ANY
```

- Success Test : I Tried API GATEWAY Endpoint ,by POSTMAN
- CRUD, AUTH, token No Error, Succssed!

---

### React Frontend

- when I Developing React Frontend, proxy setting was localhost
- localhost is backend project local server by Serverless-offline
- and used proxy...
- And I deployed S3, Cloudfront
- This is my axios instance.

```
const client = axios.create();

  client.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer JWTSECRETJWTSECRETJWTSECRET'
  client.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  client.defaults.baseURL = 'API GATEWAY ENDPOINT.COM/' 

  client.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response){
      return response;
    }, 
    function (error){
      return Promise.reject(error);
    },
  )  
  client.interceptors.request.use(
    function (request){
      return request;
    }, 
    function (error){
      return Promise.reject(error);
    },
  )
```

## NOW ERROR

1. When I Accessed Cloundfront Endpoint Can Read Post, But Can't Login.
2. In Web Console.
   Frotend Console Says : " Login Successed " but next line is
   GET https://APIGATEWAYENDPOINT.com/auth/check 401 , xhr.js:175
3. Can't Redirect, Can't save JWT Token... Login Check Stucked!

## I tried Backend CORS with Frontend Axios

```
const cors = require('@koa/cors');
...
...
...
app.use(cors({
  'allowHeaders' : ['Cookie','Content-type','Accept','Origin','X-Requested-With','Authorisation','Authorization'],
  'origin' : 'MY__.CLOUDFRONT.NET',
  'credentials' : 'true',
  'methods' : ['GET','HEAD','PUT','PATCH','POST','DELETE','OPTIONS']
}));
```

Browser Network tab Says

1. login 204 preflight, preflight OPTION
2. login 200 xhr, xhr.js:175 POST <- Can see Backend Request Payload
3. check 401 xhr, xhr.js:175 GET <- ERR!

This is 3. NETWORK MESSAGE

```
General
Request URL: https://APIGATEWAYENDPOINt/auth/check
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 
Remote Address: ___
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response Headers
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: https://_MYENDPOINT.cloudfront.net
content-length: 12
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
vary: Origin
via: 1.1 ___.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-cache: Error from cloudfront

Request Headers
:authority: ___APIGATEAWY.com
:method: GET
:path: auth/check
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
origin: https://myCLOUDFRONT.cloudfront.net
referer: https://myCLOUDFRONT.cloudfront.net/
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
sec-gpc: 1
```

What should I do?

Thx!